# Equations of ellipse

Tags: calculus

I would like to ask for your guidance to find the parametric expressions of the upper half of the following ellipse:
\begin{align*}
\frac{(x-1)^2}{4} + \frac{(y-2)^2}{9} = 1
\end{align*}
The answer is: $x(t) = 1 + 2\cos(t)$ and $y(t) = 2 + 3\cos(t)$.

However I cannot find the limits of $t$.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Isn't it $y=2+3\sin t$?

Comment: Your parameterization produces a line segment instead of the desired ellipse. That might be one reason why you’re having trouble computing the limits of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

It's common to use $X=\cos t$ and $Y=\sin t$ when parametrising $X^2+Y^2=1$.

Here:
$$X^2=\frac{(x-1)^2}{4}=\bigg(\frac{x-1}{2}\bigg)^2\implies \cos t=\frac{x-1}{2}$$
and $$Y^2=\frac{(y-2)^2}{9}=\bigg(\frac{y-2}{3}\bigg)^2\implies\sin t=\frac{y-2}{3}$$

This gives the parametric forms.

Comment: Thank you very much. And the limits of t are 0 and pi, or 0 and 2pi? Because the excercise focuses on the upper half of the ellipse.

Comment: The upper half then would mean  that $\sin t\ge 0$

Comment: Vasilis. $x=1+2\cos t$; $y= 2+3\sin t;$ Upper half: $0 \le t \le π.$ Draw it.